# Getting current Cart Id in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

So, I am using the `cart API` of Bigcommerce for adding items to the cart from a different domain which is working fine. However, when I try to repeat adding other items to the same cart it does not work. So, is there a way I can get the cart ID for an instance so that I can update my items to the existing cart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Storefront API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/storefront.html#storefront_cart_api) allows you to retrieve the current cart.

Execute this in the javascript console after adding an item to cart

```
fetch('/api/storefront/carts?include=',
{
  'credentials':'include',
  'headers':{
    'Accept':'application/json', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function(response){ 
  response.json().then(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3))
  })
});
```

returns something like this

```
[
   {
      "id": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-ccccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
      "customerId": 0,
      "email": null,
      "currency": {
         "name": "US Dollars",
         "code": "USD",
         "symbol": "$",
         "decimalPlaces": 2
      },
      "isTaxIncluded": false,
      "baseAmount": 100,
      "discountAmount": 0,
      "cartAmount": 100,
      "coupons": [],
      "discounts": [
         {
            "id": "79f73e11-87ba-4dd1-acaf-41c0098ea6ca",
            "discountedAmount": 0
         }
      ],
      "lineItems": {
         "physicalItems": [
            {
               "id": "79f73e11-87ba-4dd1-acaf-41c0098ea6ca",
               "variantId": 77,
               "productId": 112,
               "sku": "1111",
               "name": "Physical A",
               "url": "http://vanity.mybigcommerce.com/physical-a/",
               "quantity": 1,
               "isTaxable": true,
               "imageUrl": "http://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/r-de362a881829f428d7c6c20159e24db4a9c0a751/themes/ClassicNext/images/ProductDefault.gif",
               "discounts": [],
               "discountAmount": 0,
               "couponAmount": 0,
               "listPrice": 100,
               "salePrice": 100,
               "extendedListPrice": 100,
               "extendedSalePrice": 100,
               "isShippingRequired": true,
               "type": "physical",
               "giftWrapping": null
            }
         ],
         "digitalItems": [],
         "giftCertificates": []
      },
      "createdTime": "2018-05-07T19:32:19+00:00",
      "updatedTime": "2018-05-07T19:33:48+00:00"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you created your first item, the response will include Cart ID. Use this Cart ID to add more items to the same cart.

Comment: Yes that is what I am planning for but I did not find any way to get the returned cart ID. I can not save it in the session or webstorage as there is cross domain communication before add to cart process.

Comment: are you using V3 cart API or storefront cart API?

Comment: I am using v3 api.

Comment: Then storing the cart ID on your side is the only way to retain it. For storefront cart API, you could call `/api/storefront/carts` to get the current cart ID

Comment: @emaillenin this answer would benefit from 1. working code illustrating how to create the first item, and what the response would look like, and 2. urls to the documentation.